# PHP cURL response returning a string, how do I handle and select from the data?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I'm using a Codeigniter curl library to do a simple get request to a url. When I echo the response, it's coming back as a string. I can't quite figure out what I can do to convert that string into a useable format, because I need to be selecting from specific parts of the return to progress in my function.

My code is ran through Codeigniter, using Philsturgeon's curl library, here's a simple example of what I'm using:

```
$this->load->library('Curl');

$response = $this->curl->simple_get('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/username');

var_dump($response);
```

I feel like I'm missing something simple here. Any help?

Comment: could you post the response?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think the response will aid much since it's so large, but it's just a string format version of a curl response.

Comment: OK it looks like the response is in JSON, so try json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php which will return an array with the various data elements defined and identified

Comment: Sheesh, I know I tried that but with no luck. Thanks, I tried it again and now it's functional. Thanks!